# how to access a specific redux using useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux

The whole difficulty arises to get the state of a certain reducer (because of the `combineReducers`)
This problem did not arise until I used it `combineReducers`

**REDUCER**

```
const initialState = {
    caffe: [
        {
            city: "Name",
            people: "512512521",
            caffe: [
                {
                    title: "Name caffe",
                    about: "about",
                    imgLink: 'caffe',
                    url: 'urlcoffe'
                },
            ]
        }

const newcaf = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return  state;         
    }
}
export default newcaf;
```

**COMBINE REDUCER**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import caffe from './caffe'

export default combineReducers ({
    caffe
});
```

**Index.js(store)**

Regular stork

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';



const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
    && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());



ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**List cafe**

*This is where the issue happens*

```
function BlockListAdmin() {
    const caffe= useSelector(); // * how to take store from redux
    console.log(caffe)
    return (
        <>
            <div className='container'>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
    {caffe}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass a function to the `useSelector` that reads the state from the store, for example:

```
function BlockListAdmin() {
    const selectCaffe = state => state.caffe[0].caffe[0].title;
    const caffe= useSelector(selectCaffe); // * how to take store from redux
    console.log(caffe)
    return (
      <div className='container'>
         <h1>Hello</h1>
            {caffe}
      </div>
    )
}
```